# Script to sort attribute table (create new columns and fill them)

Tags: python, attribute-table, sorting

Starting situation:

I have the following element/file:

1. A shapefile that contains polygons that are parcels and their boundaries:

   - The parcels are inside a big polygon ([image: example])
   - Each parcel has a unique id, the official registration id; let’s call it REGID
   - Some parcels consist of several polygons/parts (all under the same REGID; in the attribute table they are in one row)
   - The attribute table includes following information:

     - Name, street address, ZIP code and town of the parcel’s owner (Some persons can own several parcels and some parcels have many owners)
     - If a parcel has several owners, every owner is in an own row with the REGID (One and the same REGID might be listed several times, because there are several owners assigned to the REGID)

Example of the initial attribute table ( | separates columns):

```
REGID | Owner | Address

Id1 | Owner A | Address A 

Id2 | Owner B | Address B 

Id2 | Owner C | Address C

Id3 | Owner D | Address D

Id4 |Owner B | Address B

Id4 | Owner C | Address C
```

My goal:

I want to create a shapefile that contains the following data:

- Naturally the geographic information (parcel polygons)
- The attribute table should be brought into a specific order:

  - I want to assign a MasterID to every landowner / parcel group and sort the parcels and the landowners according to a specific pattern
  - Basically, each individual REGID gets an own row and if they belong to the same owners, they’ll get the same MasterID and the information of all owners is in every row of the same MasterID

Example of the desired attribute table (using the table above):

```
MasterID | REGID | REGID2 | Owner 1 | Address 1 | Owner 2 | Address 2

MasterID1 | Id 1 | Null | Owner A | Address A | Null | Null

MasterID2 | Id 2 | Id4 | Owner B | Address B | Owner C | Address 2

MasterID2 | Id4 | Id2 | Owner B | Address B | Owner C | Address 2

MasterID3 | Id3 | Null | Owner D | Address D | Null | Null
```

I can do this manually, but I’d like to write a script that does this for me. Is this possible in QGIS? Or is this rather something for Excel?

I would prefer to use Python (I’m a real beginner though, but even more with Excel Macros).

Of course, I need to consider here that there can be more than two parcels or more than two owners as in the example above.

The script should basically do the following:

- Sort the information provided in the attribute table, by creating rows and columns automatically for each REGID (parcel id) and their landowners

  - I guess it should be according to the principle n+1 (?):

    - Automatically create new columns as many as required: Owner 1 | Address 1 | Owner2 |Address 2 | … etc
  - To my understanding it would be best to create a new attribute table as some columns/rows are not needed anymore after the data has been put together

Any hint here? Also, where should I start looking?

Comment: What have you tried by so far? If you are asking about Python, can you provide a snippet of your scripting attempts, please? Unfortunately, the GIS SE is not a platform for requesting scripts rather a platform where you demonstrate your work arounds and others assist you in improving and fixing them.

Comment: I haven't tried anything so far, because I don't know where to start. If I'd get some hints what could possibly help here what are the right tools/commands/etc, then I could start to look there and start trying something. Edit: Is what I want even possible in QGIS?

Comment: Yes, I can be wrong but I suppose you can achieve your desired output even without scripting. Did you try dealing with the Field Calculator and its functions?

Comment: Thanks. That's a good idea. I need to check that. I basically know that I need to check for double/triple/etc entries in the owner column and in the REGID column and put that information together. I'll have a look into this.

Comment: for this use case we use table relations. have you considered to move the data into several tables and set up a relation? like putting the "owner" info in one extra table and the 'pure' geographic info as well..makes life much easier!

Comment: Note that if you use Excel to sort the features you will mangle the shapefile contents (physical order is the only tie between `.shp` and `.dbf`)

Comment: Since I'm stuck with the field calculator (can't find a way to check wehether there are fields with the same value or not), I'll check the relation tool.

Comment: @sn1ks: The relation tool is interesting, never used that before. But I would need as a result exactly the table shown above. That's the setup I need so that the table can be used in QGIS and in Excel (for merged letters).

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use geopandas and pandas python libraries. Will be tricky though if you are a python beginner. Pandas is like a python excel.

Example:

```
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry.multipolygon import MultiPolygon
import pandas as pd

df = gpd.read_file('/home/bera/geoms.shp')
#Group by REGID, create fields of lists of Owners and Adresses, Create a multipart polygon of the single polygons
df2 = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df.groupby(['REGID'], as_index=False)['Owner','Address','geometry'].agg(
        {'Owner': lambda x: list(x), 'Address': lambda x: list(x), 'geometry':lambda x: MultiPolygon(list(x))}), geometry='geometry')

#From the listed Owners and Addresses create the fiels Owner1, Owner2 etc.
df_owner = pd.DataFrame(df2.Owner.tolist(), index= df2.index, columns = ['Owner_{}'.format(i) for i in range(1, df2.Owner.map(lambda x: len(x)).max()+1)])
df_adress = pd.DataFrame(df2.Address.tolist(), index= df2.index, columns = ['Adress_{}'.format(i) for i in range(1, df2.Address.map(lambda x: len(x)).max()+1)])

df = df2[['REGID','geometry']].join([df_owner, df_adress])
df = df.fillna('')

df.to_file('/home/bera/geoms2.shp')
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I would rather install FME. This shouldnt take you more than half a day with a shapefile reader -> Attribute manager -> shapefile writer